# c# Windows service is it (possible) to use the app.config

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am developing a windows service, and I am almost done,

I am doing that using Visual Studio 2012.

I am connection to the `App.config` file in order to read the connection string because the windows service deals with data installed in a database.

I am able to install this Windows service on my machine, but I am asking if this service will still be able to read from the `App.config` after being installed? or I must hard coded the connection string?

I hope I was able to explain my problem. However, If you dont' understand me, please tell me to inform you more.

Best regard,

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074563/windows-service-app-config-location

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you will be able. When you will compile your service, you will need to deploy the whole `/bin` directory. It will contains the service dependencies and actual code.

Once compiled, the `App.config` file will be renamed to: `Service.exe.config`. The content will be a copy of the `App.config`. This is the file that will be used by the service. `Service.exe` is the name of your executable. So if your executable is `AwesomeService.exe` the config file will be `AwesomeService.exe.config`.

Comment: I used to register the windows service by using `installutil myservice.exe`, but how can I register the whole `bin` folder please?

Comment: I usually use `sc create` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters I copy the content of the bin folder to the server I want to deploy to (when it is not automated), it contains the `.exe` of your service and the `.dll` that your service depends on as long as the `.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler approach would be to read the specific config file according to a specific path! Here's a working sample:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration conf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("<full path including component name.exe (and not including the '.config' part");
string PropValue = conf.AppSettings.Settings["PropertName"].Value;
```