# Using App.Config in a Windows Service in C# / Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, config

I have created a Windows Service that reads various paths from the app.config file and works correspondingly.

I also use the 'Visual Studio Installer' as a installer for my Service.

This is my project structure:

[image]

However, when I build the Installer, it does generate the .msi and .exe used to install my service, but it doesn't include the config file that it needs to use to fetch the paths it's using:

[image]

Normally, the only thing that I use is the .msi file to install and run the Windows Service (it works perfectly using hardcoded paths) but I can't seem to use it in combination with the config-file.

What I tried is to copy the config file from the service project, and paste it in the folder of the second screenshot, but the service doesn't work when I try to install and run it that way.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried adding the .config file manually in the installer project:

[image]

Without success however

Comment: check these links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515084/c-sharp-windows-service-is-it-possible-to-use-the-app-config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074563/windows-service-app-config-location

Comment: Check this, maybe you need to add config to projects output https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp2aFNtcZfk

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried to add the .config file in the project output folder, it actually puts the config file in the files folder but it doesn't use it I think

Comment: Can the person who downvoted the question please motivate the reason?

Answer (score 2):

## Nothing.

`App.config` is a part of the `Service` project and **NOT** of the installer.

It will be in the `target installation folder` of your Service assembly after installing.

Also `App.config` will be renamed according to the project's assembly name.

#### Example

Your assembly name is `Watcher.Service`, your `.exe` will be, after compiling `Watcher.Service.exe` and your `app.config` now will have the name `Watcher.Service.exe.config`.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that I have 2 seperate projects (1 is the service, the other is the installer)? I'm not sure however but it's not working if I manually copy-paste the config file to the installer project

Comment: I also added the ServiceName.exe.config file to the folder after but it also didn't work

Comment: You shouldn't add the `*.config` file manually. This is a misunderstanding of the behavior.

Comment: but if I don't, the .conf file won't show up (not even hidden) in the program folder of the service. SHouldn't there be a link between the two projects in one way or another?

Comment: The `program folder of the service` is not the folder `Debug/Release` folder?

Comment: of the service yes, but not of the installer.